# Anchor tags href not working

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, anchor

**Edit:** closing anchor fixed. This issue exists when testing on the following browsers:

- Google Chrome
- Firefox 3.5
- Safari

Works with no problems on IE 8

I'v a really weird problem here. In short, take a look at the following html:

```
<a href="login_page.html" class="img">
    <span class="img_holder">
        <img src="images/columnists/mike_zeisberger248.jpg" onerror="this.src='default.jpg'"/>
    </span>
    <span class="btn">track him</span></a>
```

Here's the `img_holder` css class:

```
.img_holder{
    border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
    display:block;
    background:#fff; 
    height: 100px
}
```

and the `img` class:

```
.img{
    _margin:0 12px 12px 0;
}
```

Now, the problem is that clicking the image nested inside the anchor tag doesn't take you to its href link (thought, the href link shows in the status bar when hovering over the image, and opens perfectly fine when opening in new tab).

Any ideas?

Comment: so, in short, the really weird part is your html skills :)
just kidding - kindof

Comment: @harry yeah my html/css skills kinda sucks, however, it's not the closing </a>

Comment: What browser are you testing?

Comment: @ekek0 it takes to a local Html file, and it's working when opening in new tab.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some browsers have issues with anchors that are `display: inline` (the default) containing elements that are `display: block`.

Add `display: block` to the ruleset with the `.img` selector.

Also see http://validator.w3.org/ — it makes a good first pass to find the low hanging fruit of QA issues. Your sample code seems to have some errors that it would pick up.

Comment: This problem exists with Firefox and Chrome too.

Comment: "Working on IE with no problems" isn't exactly the best sign that it's valid code. ;)

Comment: @jamesshannon didn't mean it's a valid code! IE means Valid code! Come on. It was a reply to David's inital answer where he stated that IE has issues with anchors that are display: inline

Answer (score 5):

Well, there area few obvious problems that spring out; one is the / before your `onerror`, and the second is that the `<a>` in question doesn't seem to be closed.

Apart from that, there doesn't seem to be any obvious reasons why it wouldn't work; perhaps a more complete post of source code is in order?

Comment: Closed it, it's not the problem anyways. just mistyped !